# Why are fields missing from my custom User object (subclassed from PFUser)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am using Parse for my app. I have a custom class called **Request**, which I have set up in Parse and in my local project. On the **Request** object, I have a **User** object. The **User** object is subclassed from **PFUser**. When a user makes a request, it is sent to the server and sent out to the appropriate users for them to accept or decline. Submitting the request works fine; everything is stored correctly in Parse. The problem is this:

After submitting the request, I log out of the current user and log in to another user's account that should receive the request that was just submitted. When I log in, I have a method:

```
+ (void)getIncomingRequestsWithCompletion: (void(^)(NSMutableArray *incomingPendingRequestsArray, NSMutableArray *incomingAcceptedRequestsArray)) complete {
  PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Request"];
  [query whereKey:@"club" equalTo:[User currentUser] [@"club"]];
  [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *incomingRequestsArray, NSError *error) {
      NSMutableArray *incomingPendingRequestsArray = [NSMutableArray new];
      NSMutableArray *incomingAcceptedRequestsArray = [NSMutableArray new];
      for (int i = 0; i < incomingRequestsArray.count; i++) {
        if ([[incomingRequestsArray objectAtIndex:i]acceptedHostUser]) {
            [incomingAcceptedRequestsArray addObject:[incomingRequestsArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
        else if (![[[incomingRequestsArray objectAtIndex:i]decliningUsers]containsObject:[User currentUser]]) {
            [incomingPendingRequestsArray addObject:[incomingRequestsArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
      }
      complete (incomingPendingRequestsArray, incomingAcceptedRequestsArray);
      NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
  }];
}
```

After this method runs, I get all the incoming requests for the current user. This method returns the requests just fine. The problem lies when I kill the app. If I kill the app, the above method will run when the user re-runs the app. The method will return the same number of requests,

> however *all of the properties on the **User** object will be missing
>   except for the objectId and a few other stock properties on the
>   **PFUser** object.*

Here is the object printed before killing the app:

```
<Request: 0x7fbe20bf5090, objectId: gEnwjj6ZIN, localId: (null)> {
    club = "<Club: 0x7fbe20b74180, objectId: cApBkG9ZFY>";
    message = "";
    requestingUser = "<PFUser: 0x7fbe2043c640, objectId: LIzd2KvDwa>";
}


<PFUser: 0x7fbe2043c640, objectId: LIzd2KvDwa, localId: (null)> {
    club = "<Club: 0x7fbe2088f5f0, objectId: KUa4N7fTgc>";
    email = "spedroza@usc.edu";
    firstName = Sergio;
    handicap = 10;
    headline = "Web Developer at University of Southern California";
    lastName = Pedroza;
    linkedInID = oOoiyTge7O;
    location = "Greater Los Angeles Area";
    phoneNumber = 5629224083;
    profileImageFile = "<PFFile: 0x7fbe208cb900>";
    username = "spedroza@usc.edu";
}
```

Here it is after:

```
<Request: 0x7fe3f3d4cd50, objectId: gEnwjj6ZIN, localId: (null)> {
    club = "<Club: 0x7fe3f3d287e0, objectId: cApBkG9ZFY>";
    message = "";
    requestingUser = "<PFUser: 0x7fe3f3d38b50, objectId: LIzd2KvDwa>";
}


<PFUser: 0x7fe3f3d38b50, objectId: LIzd2KvDwa, localId: (null)> {
}
```

Now, I have another custom object on the **Request** object. This object is the **Club** object and its custom properties are on the object whether the app has been killed or not. I have been trying to debug this for a couple days now and have had anything but luck. Any and all ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have u saved PFUser instance before killing the app?

Comment: That instance of PFUser is retrieved when I make the call to get the requests. I do not save it locally because it is an object on the _Request_ object that I'm retrieving from Parse each time that view loads. _requestingUser_ is a pointer to an individual _User_ in my Parse DB and it is saved appropriately up there, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, the User object you are missing details on is the requestingUser. Try adding this to your query before calling findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:

```
[query includeKey: @"requestingUser"]; (Objective-C)
query.includeKey("requestingUser"); (Swift)
```

Parse will only fetch stubs to objects from other classes if you do not include them in the query.

Comment: Thanks @Handsomeguy! You are indeed correct. Only thing to note is that I believe that is the Swift code. Here is the code I used for Objective C: `[query includeKey: @"requestingUser"];`

Comment: You are correct. I was using the Swift version. I will update my answer. Glad to have been of help.